# processing performance - fadeTo() vs css opacity

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have experimented repetitive event which animated by these functions:

1. Jquery animation effect: `fadeTo(1000,1);`
2. `$('#foo').on('click', function(){  $('#bar').css({"opacity":1});`

When I repeat toggling the event again and again, it seems like event is getting gradually slower.

I took a look in Task Manager in Chrome as well, however, it is quite hard to see the GPU comsumption different.

Do you have idea which one perform faster?

Comment: Faster in terms of what? The `.css()` function isn't an animation, so the change occurs straight away. Using `.fadeTo()`, on the other hand, will gradually change the opacity until it reaches the specified value, and will take the entire duration specified (in this case, 1 second).

Comment: sorry for unclear question description. I've made a change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After just running a jsPerf, it seems, as I suspected, that `fadeTo` is **significantly slower**.

In fact, for me, it was **56% slower**:

Here's the test I created, you can run it yourself: http://jsperf.com/fadeto-vs-css-opacity

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The .css method consumes far, far, far less GPU than the fadeTo