# Don't reposition remaining elements after jQuery fadeOut()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following is a simplified example of a slightly less simple game I am working on as practice:

The HTML:

```
<div>
    <img class="small" src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/rickandmorty/images/d/dd/Rick.png/revision/latest?cb=20131230003659">
    <img class="small" src="https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.111135319.1949/flat,800x800,075,f.u1.jpg">
    <img class="small" src="http://67.media.tumblr.com/c38fff03b8dd7aaf75037eb18619da57/tumblr_n436i3Falo1sndv3bo1_1280.png">
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$(".small").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

And here it is in a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rzu1yvpa

#### My Problem:

When I click on one of the images, it fades out as expected, but depending on which image disappears, the remaining images are re-positioned to fill the empty space. **How can I make the remaining images keep their positions after other images have faded out?** I have been searching and experimenting with this for a while now, but I am new to all things web, and am not sure what I should be looking for.

I have tried changing the `position` and `display` properties, but nothing has worked so far. It looks like `fadeOut()` sets the `display` property of the faded out element to `none` - maybe this is why the remaining images are ignoring them and filling the space? I have also tried putting the images in a bootstrap grid, but haven't been able to get that to work either, and would prefer a non-bootstrap solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` methods animates the opacity of the matched elements, and once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to `none`, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

This is what is causing the issue, when the display is set to `none`, the image is removed from the "flow".

You could use jQuery's `fadeTo` instead, which just fades to a degree of opacity, and does not set the display.

```
$(".small").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(600,0);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/rzu1yvpa/10/)

Answer (score 1):

you have atleast two options:

1. Just change opacity of clicked image with .fadeTo()
   (https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) that is just change of opacity (css -
   opacity to 0 with animation)
2. or harder way if you want to remove image itself you can swap it
   with div container for example with same width, heigth etc. using
   for example jq function .replaceWith()
   (http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Adeneo explains perfectly what's happening. To further optimise your code I'd suggest to use JS and a bit CSS instead:

**Javascript**

```
$('.small').on('click',function(event){
  $(this).addClass('small--animation');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.small {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}
.small--animation {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for  your suggestion. Could you please provide a little more detail on how this solution is an optimization? For this particular use case I would prefer to go with simplicity and readability over performance, but I am curious about other options since I am still learning..

Comment: Look at for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000212/processing-performance-fadeto-vs-css-opacity